# List<string> stays empty C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have created a List in my C# application and I fill this list with data in a function which operates at the beginning off the page. When I try to get to thsi data in another function, then the List returns an empty List. Does somebody knwo what I do wrong? Beneath is my code:

```
List<string> Titel = new List<string>();
List<string> Commissie = new List<string>();
List<string> Omschrijving = new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Execute();
    }
}


public void Execute()
{
    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        if (index % nthStep == 0)
        {
          Titel.Add(s);
        }
        else if(index % nthStep == 1)
        {
          Commissie.Add(s);
        }
        else
        {
          Omschrijving.Add(s);
        }
        index++;
    }               
}

protected void B1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0; i<Titel.Count; i++)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Titel[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little advice, don't do stuff like `Titel`, what I mean is don't use Dutch in programming. Most of it (programming) is English so mixing Dutch in it won't make it more readable

Comment: index  -- intialize with what value ??

Comment: In ASP.NET all objects are disposed at the end of the page's lifecylce. You have to find another way to persist them across postbacks. For example Session

Comment: Where does `words` come from and how is it populated?

Comment: Are you sure there are words in your loop that fit any of the conditions within `Execute`? Did you try to debug `Execute` and see where the lists get filled?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yes that migh because but still lot of information missing here ...

Comment: You are using two different instances of the class.  So one instance if filling the data and the other is reading a 2nd instance which doesn't have any data.